# Why doesn't raw curly constructor {} return an rvalue?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, generic-lambda

Lets say you have a variadic class with a `std::tuple`, that can be move constructed with args + 1 new arg. When constructed using `std::apply()` and a raw curly brace constructor, that constructor doesn't return an rvalue. Which means the class isn't move constructed. An example follows to clarify.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template <class... Args>
struct icecream {
    icecream() = default;

    template <class... MoreArgs>
    icecream(icecream<MoreArgs...>&& ice) {
        std::apply(
                [this](auto&&... ds) {
                    data = { std::move(ds)..., {} };
                },
                std::move(ice.data));
    }

    // This works :

    // template <class... MoreArgs>
    // icecream(icecream<MoreArgs...>&& ice) {
    //  std::apply(
    //          [this](auto&&... ds) {
    //              data = { std::move(ds)...,
    //                  std::move(std::vector<double>{}) };
    //          },
    //          std::move(ice.data));
    // }

    std::tuple<std::vector<Args>...> data{};
};

int main(int, char**) {
    icecream<int> miam;
    std::get<0>(miam.data).push_back(1);
    std::get<0>(miam.data).push_back(2);

    icecream<int, double> cherry_garcia{ std::move(miam) };

    printf("miam : \n");
    for (const auto& x : std::get<0>(miam.data)) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }

    printf("\ncherry_garcia : \n");
    for (const auto& x : std::get<0>(cherry_garcia.data)) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
miam : 
1
2

cherry_garcia : 
1
2
```

The example is a little dumbed down, but illustrates the point. In the first move constructor, `{}` is used and the tuple copy constructs. If you uncomment the second constructor with a hardcoded `std::move()`, then it works.

I test on VS latest, clang latest and gcc latest. All have the same result. (wandbox : https://wandbox.org/permlink/IQqqlLcmeyOzsJHC )

So the question is, why not return an rvalue? I'm obviously missing something with the curly constructor. This might have nothing to do with the variadic stuff, but I thought I might as well show the real scenario.

Comment: What output did you expect, that you didn't get?

Comment: && in arguments of template is not rvalue reference , it's a "universal reference". did you mean to make constructor as a template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't raw curly constructor {} return an rvalue?

The problem is another.

The problem is that

```
data = { std::move(ds)..., {} };
```

call the "direct constructor" (constructor (2) in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)),

> ```
> constexpr tuple( const Types&... args );       (2)
> ```

not the "converting constructor" (constructor (3))

> ```
> template< class... UTypes >
> constexpr tuple( UTypes&&... args );           (3)
> ```

that you expect.

The problem is that "`{}`" isn't enough, for the compiler, to deduce a type (the last type for `UTypes...` list in constructor (3)) so the constructor (3) is excluded and the compiler choose the constructor (2).

Whit constructor (2), "`{}`" is acceptable to construct an object of the last type of the `Types...` of the list because the `Types...` is know and not to be deduced.

But constructor (2) is a copy constructor (from the point of view of the `Types...` of the tuple), not a forward constructor as constructor (3), so the first vector is copied, not moved.

It's different when you call

```
data = { std::move(ds)..., std::move(std::vector<double>{}) };
```

or also

```
data = { std::move(ds)..., std::vector<double>{} };
```

because the last argument can be clearly deduced as `std::vector<double>{} &&` so the compiler call the "converting constructor" (constructor (3)) and move the content of the first vector.

Off Topic: instead of using `std::vector<double>{}`, that works only when `double` is the last of the types in `Args...`, I suggest to write a more generic code using `std::tuple_element`.

Moreover, I suggest to SFINAE enable your constructor only when `sizeof...(MoreArgs)+1u == sizeof...(Args)`.

Maybe also `std::forward()` (enabling perfect forwarding) instead of `std::move()` inside the lambda.

So I suggest the following constructor

```
template <typename ... MoreArgs,
   std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(MoreArgs)+1u == sizeof...(Args)> * = nullptr>
icecream(icecream<MoreArgs...>&& ice) {
    std::apply(
            [this](auto && ... ds) {
                data = { std::forward<decltype(ds)>(ds)..., 
                         std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Args)-1u,
                                              decltype(data)>{} };
            },
            std::move(ice.data));
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you. In this particular case, I don't want perfect forwarding as this is truly a move only design. I didn't think of using tuple_element on the member of the constructed class. That will work perfectly. thx again